# Add new object based on key:value

Tags: javascript

I have an object, I want to add a new object before each object based on `did` value. What I tried is below, but it not what I want, it add for each item, and also it turned into array.

```js
let obj = {
  "district": [{
      "id": 1,
      "uid": 1,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 1,
      "name": "text 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "uid": 2,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 2,
      "name": "text 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "uid": 3,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 2,
      "name": "text 3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "uid": 4,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 3,
      "name": "text 4"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "uid": 5,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 3,
      "name": "text 5"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "uid": 6,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 0, // should not add object before this becaus did is 0
      "name": "text 6"
    }
  ]
}


var result = obj.district.map(function(el) {
if(el.did > 0){
  var o = Object.assign({}, obj.district);
  o.divider = {
    "dv": true,
    "name": 'divider ' + el.did
  };
  return o;
}
})

console.log(result)
```

Add new object if `did` value is not null or 0, kinda > 0. the result should be like this:

```js
let obj = {
  "district": [{
      "dv": true,
      "name": "divider 1"
    }, {
      "id": 1,
      "uid": 1,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 1,
      "name": "text 1"
    },
    {
      "dv": true,
      "name": "divider 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "uid": 2,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 2,
      "name": "text 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "uid": 3,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 2,
      "name": "text 3"
    },
    {
      "dv": true,
      "name": "divider 3"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "uid": 4,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 3,
      "name": "text 4"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "uid": 5,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 3,
      "name": "text 5"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "uid": 6,
      "type": 3,
      "pid": 0,
      "cid": 0,
      "did": 0, // should not add object before this becaus did is 0
      "name": "text 6"
    }
  ]
}

console.log(obj)
```

It should add before object with common `did` id, for example if there is 5 item with `did` 2, it should just add new object once, not for each item. also name of new value should be based on `did` id, divider 1, divider 2 or ..

Comment: Mixing two different kinds data in a single array, that's not very cash money and I have never encountered a need to do something like this. Sure, that's possible, but do you really think this is the right way?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Second snippet exactly the output that what I want

Comment: @AbanaClara What I trying to do is kinda group each item, but I don't want to group by object, just want to add an object before each them

Comment: Grouping each item by array order is NOT grouping at all. This is a recipe for confusion. Each item in the original array is identified via the `id` property, why not use that instead and create a new array containing that unique identifier?

Comment: @AbanaClara `containing that unique identifier?` I have no idea what result will be output | maybe I choose wrong idea to do this, but I think this format is only way that solve my issue. what I really want is divide item based on `did` | `did` => mean s=> district id, I want to use this for drop down, and my drop down not support optgroup

Comment: Just created an array with items like so `{dv: true, id: 1, name: "divider 1"}`. The `id` property from the result array corresponds to the original `id` property of `obj.district` array. With this solution, you don't have to put items before other items, reducing complexity and potential confusion.
------
If you need this kind of array formatting because of your render algorithm, then you should format the array (without affecting the original array) during the render operation and not by modifying the source data.

Comment: @AbanaClara Can you make it as answer with example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var lastDivider;
var result = {
  district: []
}

obj.district.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.did > 0 && lastDivider !== el.did) {
    result.district.push({
      "dv": true,
      "name": 'divider ' + el.did
    });
    lastDivider = el.did;
  }
  result.district.push([Object.assign({}, el)]);
});
```

Comment: One problem, it add divider before each item, but as I said in question `it should just add new object once, not for each item`

Comment: @tourtravel I updated my answer with your comment. Just consider the comment about `flat`. :)

Comment: @tourtravel I changed the example again with a version without `flat`. Please check if this is what you are looking for. :)